# python mysql dictionary

Tags: python, mysql

I have been using the dictcursor in MySQL with Python, the problem is how I can retrieve an specific record without having to iterate in all the dictionary, actually I am using this:

```
data=cursor.fechall
for item in data:
    if item["article"]==articledesc:
           do something
           break
```

is there a way to access the element of the dictionary created directly, without having to iterate over all the elements with a for loop

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you only require a single article, then change your query to add a where clause:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE article = %s
```

Filtering a result set having retrieved more than you need is not a good idea from an efficiency point of view.

If you're retrieving a larger resultset and picking multiple articles out by name later on, you could build a rudimentary index in your first pass; then use this to efficiently access the rows by name:

```
data = cursor.fetchall()

article_index = dict((item["article"], item) for item in data)

article = article_index.get(articledesc)
if article:
   #do something
```

Comment: well not really, because I just require the information from a lot of items

Comment: @Raul generally, you should select a query filter that returns only the rows you are interested in. Your code can be converted to a query and let the database do what it does best.

Comment: I've added an alternative strategy for you

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, you can build another dictionary, but it is an implicit loop:

```
data_article = dict((item['article'], item) for item in data)
```

and then you can access data directly:

```
myitem = dict_article[articledesc]
```